# какие DNS использует wget? (unable to resolve host address)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Ubuntu 18.04 server

Не работает должным образом

```
wget http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test100Mb.db
--2021-08-08 03:58:45--  http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test100Mb.db
Resolving speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr (speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr)...
failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr’
```

Аналогичная ситуация с дригими командами.
Подозреваю, что wget не видит заданных в netplan DNS. netplan:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
        - 123.123.123.123/24
      gateway4: 123.123.123.254
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

systemd-resolve --status показывает:

```
...
Link 2 (eno1)
          Current Scopes: DNS
           LLMNR setting: yes
    MulticastDNS setting: no
          DNSSEC setting: no
        DNSSEC supported: no
             DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8
                          8.8.4.4
```

Удалил симлинк /etc/resolv.conf, сделал его файлом, установил nameserver 8.8.8.8, файл сделал доступным только для чтения, так как он после перезагрузки постоянно изменялся на локальный адрес - не помогло.

Comment: 1. [документация](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Name-Service-Switch.html). 2. актуальное значение: `$ grep hosts: /etc/nsswitch.conf`

Comment: hosts:          files dns

Comment: 1. проверьте корректность содержимого файла `/etc/resolv.conf`. 2. проведите диагностику, начав с: `$ dig +all -t any gr.`

Comment: Connection to 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) for gr. failed: timed out.

Comment: то ли вы, то ли мэйнтэйнеры используемого вами дистрибутива наконфигурировали вам использование [systemd-resolved](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/612434/110559). либо (не знаю как) меняйте конфигруацию, либо разбирайтесь, почему какой-то из потрохов замечательной операционной системы systemd не прослушивает эту связку адреса и порта (`127.0.0.53#53`).

Comment: а можно ли вообще отказаться от 127.0.0.53#53 и сразу искать на 8.8.8.8?

Comment: я же написал: `не знаю как`. поискивики вам в помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте `netstat -nupl` убедитесь что порт 53 слушается. Если да, то проверьте фаервол `iptables-save` или `nft list tables` и добавьте в исключения 127.0.0.53:53. Во многих руководствах 127.0.0.1 в исключениях, но тут .53 - обратите внимание.

Чтоб отказаться от `127.0.0.53#53` нужно отключить службы:

```
systemd-resolved
dnsmasq
resolvconf
```

Они пересоздают /etc/resolv.conf как ссылку на свою конфигурацию.

Comment: порт 53 - слушается. В iptables уже прописаны "-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT" и 
"-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT", я ничего там не трогал. Этих правил достаточно? Если отключаю iptables, то ДНС начинает работать, включаю обратно - также работает. После перезагрузки сервера - не работает.

Comment: важно чтоб правила шли в правильном порядке. закинь в вопрос выгрузку iptables-save

Comment: проблема оказалась в iptables. После перезагрузки ОС, когда работает iptables порт 53 недоступен. Если выключить и включить его обратно, порт становится доступным. Х3 почему так....